# Reindex Elasticsearch converting unixtime to date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have an Elasticsearch index which uses the `@timestamp` field to store the date in a `date` field.

There are many records which are missing the `@timestamp` field, but have a `timestamp` field containing a unix timestamp. (Generated from PHP, so seconds, not milliseconds)

Note, the `timestamp` field is of date type, but numeric data seems to be stored there.

How can I use Painless script in a reindex and set `@timestamp` where it is missing, *IF* there is a numeric `timestamp` field with a unix timestamp?

Here's an example record that I would want to transform.

```
  {
    "_index": "my_log",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "AWjEkbynNsX24NVXXmna",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "name": null,
      "pid": "148651",
      "timestamp": 1549486104
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [ingest module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) of Elasticsearch??

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-processor.html

> Parses dates from fields, and then uses the date or timestamp as the
>   timestamp for the document. By default, the date processor adds the
>   parsed date as a new field called @timestamp. You can specify a
>   different field by setting the target_field configuration parameter.
>   Multiple date formats are supported as part of the same date processor
>   definition. They will be used sequentially to attempt parsing the date
>   field, in the same order they were defined as part of the processor
>   definition.

It does exactly what you want :) In your reindex statement you can direct documents through this ingest processor.

If you need more help let me know, then I can jump behind a computer and help out :D